# Load entire page in a div

Tags: hyperlink, html

I have 5 websites, each on their own URL. I want to make a site that will take the main div from those websites and display it inside a specified div. Where can I start looking to make such website?

Comment: Easiest is using an iframe. If you only would load some contents off another site then you will have pitfalls with css, js, relative img-paths and so on...But then of course you dont just get the main div...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jQuery, you can use the .load() function. It can take a url and optional css selector argument and load it into for instance a div:

$("#yourdiv").load("http://url .content");

Comment: is it possible to load the content div only from the outside url?

Comment: Yes, you can just use the css selector after the url. replace ".content" above with "#idOfYourContentDiv".

Answer (score 0):

```
Just point an IFrame at each site address.    

<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <iframe src="http://www.site1.com"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create on javacript function which will do afunction of diplaying and creting a div.

now put that function in script tag and make one embeded code ...after that use that embeded code to all the other websites where you want that div to be presented. at that time that function will be callled from the first site on your own site.

or

second way to display div use webservice which grabs the dtata from one place and didplay on your site